# Calculate the mean across rows excluding min and max values?

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following dataframe:

| col_a | col_b | col_c | col_d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -100 | 2 | 4 | 100 |
| -200 | 4 | 8 | 200 |

I'd like to calculate the mean across rows excluding the minimum and maximum values:

| col_a | col_b | col_c | col_d | mean_exc_min_max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -100 | 2 | 4 | 100 | 3 |
| -200 | 4 | 8 | 200 | 6 |

I know I can use [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) via `mean(axis=1)` but I can't figure out how to exclude the min and max values. The datasets I'm dealing with are pretty large so ideally I'm looking for a solution that's vectorised.

Any ideas?

Code to create the dataframe:

```
data = {
    "col_a": [-100, -200],
    "col_b": [2, 4],
    "col_c": [4, 8],
    "col_d": [100, 200],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Sorting algorithm is usually efficient and optimized, would you consider to sort the Df first in a temp place and then just do mean on the sorted Df, excluding the first and last item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python one-liner:

```
df['mean_exc_min_max'] = (df.sum(1)-df.min(1)-df.max(1))/2
```

Comment: Hi! Since she said the datasets are pretty large, maybe devided by (len(df.columns)-2) might be more ideal?

Comment: Yes that can be done or if we know how many columns are there, we can subtract that number by two and divide by it. (In above case it comes out to be 2).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an easy way:

```
df['MIN_DELETE']=df.min(axis=1)  #find the MIN 
df['MAX_DELETE']=df.max(axis=1)  #find the MAX 
df['MIN_DELETE'] = -df['MIN_DELETE']  #negative numbers of MIN
df['MAX_DELETE'] = -df['MAX_DELETE']  #negative numbers of MAX
df['mean_exc_min_max']=df.sum(axis = 1)/(len(df.columns)-4)  
#sum of entire row (MAX+MIN+MAX_DELETE+MIN_DELETE=0)
#devided by number of columns without 4 columns
df.drop(['MAX_DELETE', 'MIN_DELETE'], axis=1)  #drop MAX_DELETE and MIN_DELETE
```

Edit: You need to find the MAX and MIN first, then do the negative value